# Tomcat startup exception

Tags: tomcat6

When i startup tomcat i m getting this exception. I m using Tomcat6.0. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

```
   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearThreadLocalMap
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't tell, based on what you posted.

If I cut & paste your message into Google, it brings back this:

http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/MemoryLeakProtection